# How to solve bug with <h1> and all heading  tags in Safari browser?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, encoding, safari

I'm running RubyOnRails application and have set charset in my application.html.erb:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
 <h3>Some text</h3>
```

I have strange bug - when I put text in h1,...,h6 tag looks like this:

[image]

I tried different charsets, but nothing worked. Also looked at Safari settings and set encoding UTF-8.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Are other HTML tags showing content fine?

Comment: Show the complete source for the header tag. Is this only in Safari?

Comment: Of course I can avoid them, but it will be problem avoiding.

Comment: Please post a complete example that demonstrates the problem, preferable a minimal self-contained HTML document that anyone can open in the browser and see the issue.

Comment: @Dipaks, from Firebug `font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  font-family: Verdana, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif !important; 

 line-height: 30px;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is in font...With your fonts it looks ok. Is this means, that my fonts are incorrect ?

Comment: @MID Some custom fonts might have been affecting the heading tags. Did this work?

Comment: Yes.Your font looks normal, but mine are not( So the problem is in font - "Helvetica Neue". Can I get it somewhere ?

Comment: Here it is in my previous comment.

Comment: @MID Many operating systems don't have 'Helvetica Neue' installed. You always have to use fallback fonts too

Comment: One stupid question : I thaught, that when I'm using this code `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", helvetica; ` if Helvetiva Neue not found it will use hevletica, but I do have Helvetica Neue, because it is showing, but it seems to be damaged or how can you explain this ?

Comment: I was using Helvetica Neue for one of may project and had similar issue. Eventually I decided to use Google Web Font which was very similar to Helvetica Neue :) It's a kinda buggy font

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and consultation.